# Javascript.Run Multi promises Synchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous, co

I want to request a website for 40 times.

I want this to be synchronously, like 10 requests 4 times.

**This is My code for 1 request - 40 times:**

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var co = require('co');


function callUrl(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(url, (e, r, b) => {
            if (e) reject(e)
            else
                resolve(`Response from ${url}`);
        });
    })
}


co(function*() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 41; i++) {
            let rs = yield callUrl('https://www.google.com/?q=' + i);
            // let rs = yield makeUrls(10,i);
            console.log(rs);
        }
    });
```

I can make an array of promises, but I can't figure it out how to change the value of `q` to be different.

Comment: do you want to pass the result of each promise to the next or just fire them synchronously w/o direct relation?

Comment: I want to fire them in a chain, I don't want to loop through each URL.
Imagine I have to do `10 000` requests. I want to fire multiple promises at once. I don't want them all at once cause I could've DDOS the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to run them synchronously - you want to synchronize them - those are different.

You'd use an array of promises together with `Promise#all`. When you create a promise the action is already being executed - only `yield` synchronizes things.

You can make 10 requests at once like so:

```
co(function*() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 41;) {
        var promises = [];
        for(var lim = i + 10; i < Math.max(lim, 41); i++) {
           promises.push(callUrl('https://www.google.com/?q=' + i));
        }
        let rs = yield Promise.all(promises); // wait for everything
        console.log(rs); // an array of 10 results
});
```

Note that in addition to that, your code is still not very efficient - what happens if 9 out of 10 requests are really fast and one takes a minute? You'll only have one outgoing requests. You can use a library like `bluebird` which has a more efficient `Promise.map` method with a concurrency parameter.

Comment: It works, thank you.
But please explain me the `for` loop that pushes the promises into an array.

I can't figure out why `j++`

Comment: You're right, I don't actually need a second counter (I did it since I was using j in the callUrl).

Answer (score 0):

this might work w/o using generators

```
const urls = [/*array of urls*/];
const initialPromise = request[urls[0]];
let promise = initialPromise;
for(let i= 1; i<40;i++){
  let thenFunction = response => {
    //do something with the response
    return request(urls[i])
  }
  promise = promise.then(thenFunction)
}
```

the idea behind this is to build the chain of promises so the next one will waif for the previous one to finish

Comment: this was a generator-les  approach in case he was interested